# How do I fix glitchy/jittering exported render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export

I'm new to blender, and trying to make cinematic car animation, but I don't know why my render is super glitchy/jittering I've tried to rendered it again but still the same, so where did I go wrong? Please let me know because currently I'm struggling with it and it really killed my motivation to learn blender.

This is the animation btw:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cYalNYuoVtfd_zZdPz1mzjsI4jR8hVYs/view?usp=sharing

Another example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10gRqLhmoUm4B4f9V9m_HeX_NKjUKLN34/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.